# Flatten values of every key in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, flatten

I have a dictionary like this:

```
migration_dict = {'30005': ['key42750','key43119', 'key44103', ['key333'],
['key444'], ['keyxx']], '30003': ['key43220', 'key42244','key42230',
['keyzz'], ['kehh']]}
```

How can I flatten the values of every key in order to have something like this:

```
migration_dict = {'30005': ['key42750','key43119', 'key44103', 'key333',
'key444', 'keyxx'], '30003': ['key43220', 'key42244','key42230',
'keyzz', 'kehh']}
```

Comment: How many levels are in your dictionaries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write a recursive function to *flatten* the value lists and use it in a dictionary comprehension to build a new dictionary:

```
def flatten(lst):
   for x in lst:
      if isinstance(x, list):
         for y in flatten(x): # yield from flatten(...) in Python 3
            yield y           #
      else:
         yield x

migration_dict = {k: list(flatten(v)) for k, v in dct.items()}
print(migration_dict)
# {'30005': ['key42750', 'key43119', 'key44103', 'key333', 'key444', 'keyxx'], '30003': ['key43220', 'key42244', 'key42230', 'keyzz', 'kehh']}
```

It handles any nesting depth in the dict value lists.

Comment: Helpful, just for curiosity what if there is `interger` in our list ? like `l = [[1],2,3]` , I tried it but  with `flatten()`, but it says `int object is not iteratble`

Comment: @akashkarothiya Works the same, not sure how you're using the function. The ints are caught in the `else`, while the inner list(s) is processed recursively. Gives `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: Just here to nitpick that this will run forever if any list has a reference to itself in it ;) (+1 ofc)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye oh Yes, my bad thanks again, Is there any in-built function like `flatten` in python, here you wrote UDF ?

Comment: @timegb Highly unlikely, but good observation. Patch: `if x is lst: raise ValueError('The list is self referencing')`

Comment: @akashkarothiya I don't know of any that handles arbitrary depths.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye ok, thanks again, i wish i could give more than +1, really helpful

Comment: @timgeb With "runs forever" you mean "until it hits the recursion-limit"? :)

Comment: How to handle RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object error?

Answer (score 2):

```
for key in migration_dict:
    for i in migration_dict[key]:
        if type(i) == list:
            migration_dict[key].remove(i)
            for element in i:
                migration_dict[key].append(element)
```

Now this loop should do it. Note however, that this works only if the inner list doesn't have more lists within it. If it does then you might have to make a recursive function that flattens it out for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using an 3rd party extension, you could use [`iteration_utilities.deepflatten`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/deepflatten.html)<sup>1</sup> and a dict-comprehension:

```
>>> from iteration_utilities import deepflatten
>>> {key: list(deepflatten(value, ignore=str)) for key, value in migration_dict.items()}
{'30003': ['key43220', 'key42244', 'key42230', 'keyzz', 'kehh'],
 '30005': ['key42750', 'key43119', 'key44103', 'key333', 'key444', 'keyxx']}
```

This flattens all iterable items in your values (except strings).

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclaimer: I'm the author of that library

Answer (score 0):

Heres a oneliner:

Consider this dict, same structure:

```
m =  {'a': ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', ['k4'], ['k5'], ['k6']],
     'b': ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', ['k4'], ['k5'], ['k6']]}

import itertools

d = {k:list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x,1) if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in v)) for k,v in m.iteritems()}

{'a': ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k5', 'k6'],
 'b': ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k5', 'k6']}
```

You could also use a 3rd party library `more-iterools`,

```
t = {k: list(more_itertools.collapse(v, base_type=str)) for k,v in m.iteritems()}

 {'a': ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k5', 'k6'],
 'b': ['k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4', 'k5', 'k6']}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its important to have flat values in your dictionary, maybe you could create a function that gets rid of all the (multi-dimensional)lists before adding them to the dictionary?

```
def flatten_values(value):
      if type(value) == list:
           for i in value:
                return i
```

Hope this helps, couldnt make this into a comment, because i don't have enough rep ;)